# I want to find the number in between a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to find how to get the in between of a number in a list using inBetween as a public method.

DoubleLinked Class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList
   {
   private Link first;               // ref to first item
   private Link last;                // ref to last item
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public DoublyLinkedList()         // constructor
      {
      first = null;                  // no items on list yet
      last = null;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean isEmpty()          // true if no links
      { return first==null; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void insertFirst(long dd)  // insert at front of list
      {
      Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link

      if( isEmpty() )                // if empty list,
         last = newLink;             // newLink <-- last
      else
         first.previous = newLink;   // newLink <-- old first
      newLink.next = first;          // newLink --> old first
      first = newLink;               // first --> newLink
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void insertLast(long dd)   // insert at end of list
      {
      Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link
      if( isEmpty() )                // if empty list,
         first = newLink;            // first --> newLink
      else
         {
         last.next = newLink;        // old last --> newLink
         newLink.previous = last;    // old last <-- newLink
         }
      last = newLink;                // newLink <-- last
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Link deleteFirst()         // delete first link
      {                              // (assumes non-empty list)
      Link temp = first;
      if(first.next == null)         // if only one item
         last = null;                // null <-- last
      else
         first.next.previous = null; // null <-- old next
      first = first.next;            // first --> old next
      return temp;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Link deleteLast()          // delete last link
      {                              // (assumes non-empty list)
      Link temp = last;
      if(first.next == null)         // if only one item
         first = null;               // first --> null
      else
         last.previous.next = null;  // old previous --> null
      last = last.previous;          // old previous <-- last
      return temp;
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
                                     // insert dd just after key
   public boolean insertAfter(long key, long dd)
      {                              // (assumes non-empty list)
      Link current = first;          // start at beginning
      while(current.dData != key)    // until match is found,
         {
         current = current.next;     // move to next link
         if(current == null)
            return false;            // didn't find it
         }
      Link newLink = new Link(dd);   // make new link

      if(current==last)              // if last link,
         {
         newLink.next = null;        // newLink --> null
         last = newLink;             // newLink <-- last
         }
      else                           // not last link,
         {
         newLink.next = current.next; // newLink --> old next
                                      // newLink <-- old next
         current.next.previous = newLink;
         }
      newLink.previous = current;    // old current <-- newLink
      current.next = newLink;        // old current --> newLink
      return true;                   // found it, did insertion
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public Link deleteKey(long key)   // delete item w/ given key
      {                              // (assumes non-empty list)
      Link current = first;          // start at beginning
      while(current.dData != key)    // until match is found,
         {
         current = current.next;     // move to next link
         if(current == null)
            return null;             // didn't find it
         }
      if(current==first)             // found it; first item?
         first = current.next;       // first --> old next
      else                           // not first
                                     // old previous --> old next
         current.previous.next = current.next;

      if(current==last)              // last item?
         last = current.previous;    // old previous <-- last
      else                           // not last
                                     // old previous <-- old next
         current.next.previous = current.previous;
      return current;                // return value
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayForward()
      {
      System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
      Link current = first;          // start at beginning
      while(current != null)         // until end of list,
         {
         current.displayLink();      // display data
         current = current.next;     // move to next link
         }
      System.out.println("");
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayBackward()
      {
      System.out.print("List (last-->first): ");
      Link current = last;           // start at end
      while(current != null)         // until start of list,
         {
         current.displayLink();      // display data
         current = current.previous; // move to previous link
         }
      System.out.println("");
      }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class DoublyLinkedList
```

InBetweenDemo Class as the Main class:

```
public class InBetweenDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {                             // make a new list
      DoublyLinkedList theList = new DoublyLinkedList();

      theList.insertFirst(22);      // insert at front
      theList.insertFirst(44);
      theList.insertFirst(66);

      theList.insertLast(11);       // insert at rear
      theList.insertLast(33);
      theList.insertLast(55);

      theList.displayForward(); 
      int n=55;// display list forward
      System.out.println("inBetween("+n+") "+ theList.inBetween(n));

      theList.deleteFirst();        // delete first item
      theList.displayForward(); 
      n=55;
      System.out.println("inBetween("+n+") "+ theList.inBetween(n));

      theList.deleteLast(); 
      theList.displayForward(); 
      n=33;
      System.out.println("inBetween("+n+") "+ theList.inBetween(n));
      theList.deleteKey(22);        // delete item with key 11
      theList.displayForward(); 

      System.out.println("inBetween("+n+") "+ theList.inBetween(n));
      n=99;
      System.out.println("inBetween("+n+") "+ theList.inBetween(n));

      theList.displayForward();     // display list forward

      theList.insertAfter(11, 77);  // insert 77 after 22
      theList.insertAfter(33, 88);  // insert 88 after 33

      theList.displayForward();     // display list forward
      }  // end main()
   }  // end class DoublyLinkedApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I was planning for the inBetween method to accept an item as its parameter and return true if the item is in between the smallest and largest element in that list. Otherwise, the method returns false. However I am not sure how to write it in code. Also, I wonder if the item if the smallest item is deleted in the list or the biggest item is deleted in the list, the program might not know which item is the largest and smallest. So should I also use a method to get max and min first?

Comment: max() and min() would be indeed usefull methods. One could then do something along the lines of inBetween(int n) { return !isEmpty() ? max() >= n && min() <= n) : false; }. The mix() and max() could either traverse the whole list for or the min and max values could be held in member variables and updated upon list change.

Comment: Just curious but they can just be based on elements not the actual numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create inBetween method such that it takes number as a parameter and inside you can call a method in which you will implement your algorithm of determining min and max value in the list. **NOTE** This will only work if your list is globally defined and not in a specific method, otherwise you will have to provide the list as a parameter to inBetween method as well. So in pseudocode you can do:

```
inBetween(numberToBeChecked):
   max = getMax(yourList)
   min = getMin(yourList)        // you can implement this in one method and return an array containing of two elements for example. It's your choice.
   if (numberToBeChecked > min && numberToBeChecked < max):
          return True
   else:
          return False
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand you would write int n inside the parameters inBetween(numberToBeChecked). Since int n is the specified number. However, I am unsure if I can write the max and min in that way as in my DoublyLinked class I did not write a max and min method. Would I replace the max and min with the current and previous?

Comment: You can write min and max in such way, because you are passing your list as a parameter, you don't have to have method inside your list implementation. Inside your min and max method you can use for or any other loop to iterate over your list and to capture your minimum i.e your maximum number.

Comment: So my min and max are my variables. Yet would I create the getMax and getMin methods as an if statement inside my inBetween() method?

Comment: Yes, min and max are variables. getMin and getMax would be methods which you can implement anywhere and call them in your inBetween method.

Comment: The problem I have with getMin and getMax is that it will become a sorted linked list instead of an unsorted linked list. What would you recommend I should do?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. Thanks for the help!